# List all files recursively in git repository in tree format on Windows

Tags: git, tree

Is there something equivalent to `tree` in git bash on windows? I want to list all files and directories recursively. I know there is something like `git ls-files` but i prefer tree format. I am designing application directory structure and such tool would be very helpful.

Comment: `I want to list all files and directories recursively` Why don't you just use `tree` or `ls -R`?

Comment: I found there is tree.com program on windows, I think I could use this.

Comment: @smarber because that includes all of the `gitignored` stuff you don't care about - cache files, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://superuser.com/questions/1072422/how-to-display-git-ls-file-result-in-a-tree-like-format

[gitree](https://github.com/jpwilliams/gitree) does exactly this.

Install it with `npm i -g @jpwilliams/gitree`

and run `gitree` to get nice output like this:

[image: gitree output]